# Whenever I change my `geometry.setDrawRange` property, synchronization stops

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using the following render loop in order to attach a cube to the "head" of a line (`BuffGeometry line`).
When I set the line's `geometry.SetDrawRange` to (0, drawRange), I get good reaction.

```
                line1.geometry.setDrawRange( 0, drawCount );
                line2.geometry.setDrawRange( 0, drawCount );
//blahblah
                var positioning = buffGeometry2.getAttribute('position');
                if (drawCount%3 == 0){
                    cube.position.x = positioning.array[drawCount*3 + 0];//(line1.geometry.attributes.position.array[drawCount]);
                    cube.position.y = positioning.array[drawCount*3 + 1];//(line1.geometry.attributes.position.array[drawCount + 1]);
                    cube.position.z = positioning.array[drawCount*3 + 2];
                }
```

But when I want to limit my line's length: `geometry.SetDrawRange(drawRange-20, drawRange)`, the cube's position isn't synchronized with the line's head position. To do so I've replaced the 2 lines of `setDrawRange` to:

```
            if (drawCount > 20){
                line1.geometry.setDrawRange( drawCount-20, drawCount );
                line2.geometry.setDrawRange( drawCount-20, drawCount );

            }
            else{
                line1.geometry.setDrawRange( 0, drawCount );
                line2.geometry.setDrawRange( 0, drawCount );
            }
```

I've left the else untouched. Now, whenever the draw limit is reached (20 steps), the cube stays on the lines path, but can't stick up to the lines' pace.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just found out my BUG.
As I could not find a proper documentation on setDrawRange, I came across a tutorial that explained me the follow:
`setDrawRange(<start>, <count>)`
and not 
`setrDrawRange(<start>, <finish>)` as I thought....